# Pre checking checkbox when passing data between forms using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an HTML form using Javascript to pass data in between pages and I'm successful for the most part except for the checkboxes. Is it possible to make sure the check boxes stay checked going to the next page? or is it better to put the checkboxes on the 2nd page where the actual information will be submitted? Thanks!

Comment: Save the checkbox state in `localStorage`, then when the new page loads, update all the boxes based on what you saved.

Comment: are you using `POST` or `GET` method? hmmm, i think its possible to make sure the check boxes stay checked going to the next page and its better. can you post some code of `htm` and `javascript`?

Comment: How are you "using javascript to pass data between pages"? Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using `sessionStorage` to save the state of the check boxes. The state of the check boxes is preserved even if you reload the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
      function loadOldValues(){
        checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")
        for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i){
          if(sessionStorage.getItem(checkboxes[i].id) == "true"){
            checkboxes[i].checked = true
          }
        }
      }
      function saveOldValues(){
        checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")
        for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i){
          checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", function(){
            sessionStorage.setItem(this.id, this.checked)
          })
        }
      }
      addEventListener("load", loadOldValues)
      addEventListener("load", saveOldValues)
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      Form:<br>
      <label for="checkbox1">Check 1:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"><br>
      <label for="checkbox2">Check 2:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"><br>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can find more about storage here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage